# Negation of double universal quantifications

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

In logic, when I want to negate the formula

$$\forall x \forall y( F(y) \land A(y) \to \neg G(x,y))$$

what is the correct equivalent? Intuitively, I think it gives

$$\exists x \forall y (F(y) \land A(y) \land G(x,y))$$

but I'm not to sure about it.

Comment: No: $¬∀x$ is equivalent to: $∃x¬$. Thus $¬∀x∀y$, moving inside the $¬$ sign step by step, gives: $∃x∃y¬$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So is it correct that this will give me: ∃x∃y¬((F(y)∧A(y)→¬G(x,y)) so ∃x∃y(F(y)∧A(y)∧G(x,y)) ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA: You should have written that comment as an answer. =)